# Listview items were added in wrong place

Tags: android, listview

I am using listview with dynamic items.It is saving in wrong place(That means 1st item showing in third item, second item showing in 5th item, etc).I dont know how to solve this one.I have added the relevant code.Please check it.

**EDIT**:

**UpcomingGoalAdapter.java:**

```
public class UpcomingGoalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UpcomingGoalItems> {
    private Context context;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private List<UpcomingGoalItems> items;
    String eventIdForVol;
    private UpcomingGoalAdapter adapter;
    String userIdStr, tokenStr;

    public UpcomingGoalAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<UpcomingGoalItems> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = objects;
        this.adapter = this;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        final UpcomingGoalItems rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapt_upcoming_goal, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvInterest = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_interest_goal_adapt);
            holder.ivEdit = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_edit_goal_adapt);
            holder.tvCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_count_goal_adapt);
            holder.ivDelete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_delete_goal_adapt);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        if((rowItem.getInterest().equals(null) || rowItem.getInterest().equals(""))
                && (rowItem.getLocation().equals(null) || rowItem.getLocation().equals(""))
                && (rowItem.getFromDate().equals(null) || rowItem.getFromDate().equals(""))
                && (rowItem.getToDate().equals(null) || rowItem.getToDate().equals(""))) {

            holder.tvInterest.setText("-");

        } else {

            holder.tvInterest.setText("Looking for "+rowItem.getInterest() + " in " + rowItem.getSplitLocation() + " On ( "
                    + rowItem.getFromDate() + " - " + rowItem.getToDate()+" ) ");
        }


        holder.tvCount.setText(rowItem.getCount());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvInterest;
        ImageView ivEdit;
        TextView tvCount;
        ImageView ivDelete;
    }
```

**UpcomingGoalActivity.java:**

```
        ArrayList<UpcomingGoalItems> itemsaArrayList;
        UpcomingGoalAdapter itemsAdapter;
        ListView listView;

        itemsaArrayList = new ArrayList<UpcomingGoalItems>();
            itemsAdapter = new UpcomingGoalAdapter(UpcomingGoalActivity.this, R.layout.adapt_upcoming_goal, itemsaArrayList);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_interest_goal_search);

        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        hitGoalApi();


  private void hitGoalApi(){


        String myGoalsUrl = PK_MY_GOALS;
        Log.e("myGoalsUrl", myGoalsUrl);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, myGoalsUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                dialog.dismiss();

                if(response != null && !response.startsWith("<HTML>")){

                    Log.e("MyGoalsRes", response);

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        JSONArray jsonArrData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                        for(int i=0; i < jsonArrData.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject getDataJsonObj = jsonArrData.getJSONObject(i);

                            LOCATION = getDataJsonObj.getString("location");

                            String[] placeArray = LOCATION.split("\\s*,\\s*");

                            Log.e("placeArray", ""+ Arrays.toString(placeArray));

                            String placeStr = placeArray[0];

                            FROM_DATE = getDataJsonObj.getString("fromdate");

                            TO_DATE = getDataJsonObj.getString("todate");

                            GOAL_ID = getDataJsonObj.getString("g_id");

                            getInterest = getDataJsonObj.getString("users_interest_goals");

                            hitCountApi(GOAL_ID, placeStr, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE, getInterest);



                        }

                    }

                    catch (JSONException e){

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }else{

                    toastShort(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet");
                }

            }
        } 


    private void hitCountApi(final String goalId, final String splitLoc, final String fromDate,
                             final String toDate, final String getInteresn) {


        String countUrl = PK_GOAL_SEARCH + goalId + ".json";
        Log.e("countUrl", countUrl);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, countUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                dialog.dismiss();

                if (response != null && !response.startsWith("<HTML>")) {

                    Log.e("CountRes", response);

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        JSONObject metaJsonObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_metadata");

                        String totalRecStr = metaJsonObj.getString("total_records");

                        Log.e("totalRecStr", "" + totalRecStr);

                        UpcomingGoalItems items = new UpcomingGoalItems();

                        items.setSplitLocation(splitLoc);
                        items.setFromDate(fromDate);
                        items.setToDate(toDate);
                        items.setGoalId(goalId);
                        items.setInterest(getInterest);
                        items.setCount(totalRecStr);                    ;

                        itemsaArrayList.add(items);
                        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {

                    toastShort(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet");
                }

            }
        })
```

Based on the Volley response order I have to show the right id for listview.It takes wrong order.

Let me know why it is ordering at wrong place and how to solve this.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: Use ArrayList instead of List:

```
private ArrayList<UpcomingGoalItems> items;
```

The ArrayAdapters I use tend to look like this:

(the ArrayList< String> names is an ArrayList created from the names of the ArrayList< Task>)

```
public class ArrayAdapterTask extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private int layoutId;
    private ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    public ArrayAdapterTask(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Task> tasks, int layoutId) {
        super(context, layoutId, names);

        this.context = context;
        this.tasks = null;
        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Do stuff with the tasks.get(position)
    }
}
```